# Web Part to view photos from SharePoint Library

Tags: c#, sharepoint, web-parts

I am trying to develop a web part that will display a random photo from my photo library.

I have been able to successfully loop through and select a random photo from the library. My issue now is to display this photo on the SharePoint site. I have tried creating an image control and setting the url to the url I retrieve and programmatically add an image control but the image does not seem to display on the page after the web part loads. It simply shows a red X saying the image could not be displayed.

If I navigate to the URL of the photo in the browser it is diplayed but not when the web part tries to pull it down.

Can anybody give me a pointer? I'm still a SharePoint beginner

Here is what I have so far:

```
       Random randomNumber;
       randomNumber = new Random();

       Controls.Clear();
       ClearChildState();
       SPWeb thisWeb = SPContext.Current.Web;

       SPPictureLibrary pictures = (SPPictureLibrary)thisWeb.Lists["Houston Photos"];
       int pictureCount = pictures.ItemCount;
       int index = randomNumber.Next(pictureCount);
       string source = thisWeb.Url + "/" + pictures.Items[index].Url;
       String itemHtml = String.Format(@"<img SRC={0}+height=200px> </img>",source);
       this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(itemHtml));
       imgControl.ImageUrl = source;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say it's your img tag that's the problem

try something like

```
string itemHtml = string.concat("<img src=\"", source, "\" height=\"200\" />);
```

You could also use the Image class control, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.image.aspx

```
Random randomNumber;
randomNumber = new Random();

Controls.Clear();
ClearChildState();
SPWeb thisWeb = SPContext.Current.Web;

SPPictureLibrary pictures = (SPPictureLibrary)thisWeb.Lists["Houston Photos"];
int pictureCount = pictures.ItemCount;
int index = randomNumber.Next(pictureCount);
string source = thisWeb.Url + "/" + pictures.Items[index].Url;

var image = new Image();
image.ImageUrl = source;
image.Height = 200;
this.Controls.Add(image);
```